# MySQL 5.7 - Calling procedure with dynamic name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.7, dynamic-sql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to write a MySQL (5.7) procedure that dynamically calls another procedure based on the one of its inputs.

The code I came up with so far is this (`procedure_exists` works for checking whether or not the function is available):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE process_event (IN event_type VARCHAR(32), IN aggregate_id CHAR(36), IN payload JSON)
BEGIN
    DECLARE handler_name VARCHAR(38) DEFAULT CONCAT('handle', event_type);

    IF procedure_exists(handler_name) THEN
        SET @handler_sql = CONCAT('CALL ', handler_name, '(?,?)');

        PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @handler_sql;

        SET @aggregate_id = aggregate_id;
        SET @payload = payload;

        EXECUTE prepared_statement USING @aggregate_id, @payload;
    END IF;
END;
```

The procedure is called from this trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER events_before_insert BEFORE INSERT ON events FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE next_sequence BIGINT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT COALESCE(new.sequence, COALESCE(MAX(sequence), 0) + 1) FROM events INTO next_sequence;

    SET new.sequence = next_sequence;
    SET new.recorded_at = COALESCE(new.recorded_at, NOW());

    CALL process_event(new.event_type, new.aggregate_id, new.payload);
END //
```

This doesn't work however, because I keep getting

`[0A000][1336] Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger`

From what I understand, disallowing that by default makes perfect sense, but from what I've gathered there seems to be no way of opting in to theoretically less secure behavior, by allowing certain types of statements or disabling the check altogether.

Do you have any suggestions for getting this to work?

In short the question boils down to this:

> Can I somehow have a procedure to which I pass `event_type (VARCHAR(32))`, `aggregate_id (CHAR(36))` and `payload (JSON)` which will then automatically call `handle{event_type}(aggregate_id, payload)` if it exists?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?   In databases where it is possible, eg. Oracle, it still isn't such a good idea if you like performance and scalability.

Comment: It's a very basic event sourcing implementation, moving the actual processing of events into the DB layer for immediate consistency guarantees. As a workaround I have a procedure that wraps storing the event and  the call to `process_event` in a transaction. That works fine, but doesn't feel as neat as simply using the trigger for it.

Comment: Another argument against such an approach is the argument against using dynamic SQL *ever* and that is you absolutely can't safely accept something like `handler_name` as input and just prepare a statement with it, because the code building the prepared statement is now set up to become a confused deputy and helpfully execute a malicious instruction injected somewhere upstream.  But if you have a known/defined set of handler names, you accomplish your purpose with a case statement.

Comment: It looks like you have another antipattern: `SELECT COALESCE(new.sequence, COALESCE(MAX(sequence), 0) + 1) FROM events INTO next_sequence;` will fall apart rapidly and produce duplicate values with just a small amount of concurrency.  Use an auto-increment or at least consider `UUID_SHORT()` which returns a monotonic bigint unsigned.